# How can I get only the objectId of document in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to get only the objectId from mongodb with matched crieteria.I can get it with dbobject and cursor method.But I used mongo client here and have no idea how to do it.
Thanking you

```
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("baazaronline");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database
            .getCollection("Attribute");

    Bson filter = new Document("attcode", attcode);

    Bson newValue = new Document("DefautV", DefautV).append("IVSO", IVSO).append("UniqueV", UniqueV).append("ValuesR", ValuesR).append("Visiblename", Visiblename).append("citso", citso).append("values",values);
    Bson updateOperationDocument = new Document("$set", newValue);
    collection.updateOne(filter, updateOperationDocument);

    client.close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `findOneAndUpdate` which returns the `Document` as result and map the `_id`.

Something like

```
ObjectId id = collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateOperationDocument).get("_id", ObjectId.class);
```

Update: Include `Projection` to limit the response to only contain _id field.

```
FindOneAndUpdateOptions findOneAndUpdateOptions = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions();
findOneAndUpdateOptions.projection(Projections.include("_id"));
ObjectId id  =  collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateOperationDocument, findOneAndUpdateOptions).getObjectId("_id");
```

Comment: Thank you,your answer is very helpful.But I want to get id from this document only and dont want to use id to update document.

Comment: You are welcome. You are not. What makes you say that ?

Comment: I want to use it in JUnit test, how can I do it? with the filter, updateOperationDocument etc as parameter because it complaint.