# JUnit testing to get ObjectID in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, junit

Reading from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474680/how-can-i-get-only-the-objectid-of-document-in-mongodb-using-java) about getting the `ObjectID` in `MongoDB`. Although I googled it but nothing about the `JUnit` testing with MongoDB. Is that anyway I can get this Id to test if user exist in JUnit test?

Below is the JUnit test,

```
public class UserDAOTest2 {

    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
        //fail("Not yet implemented");
        
        User user1 = new User();
        
        user1.setEmail("lucy@gmal.com");
        user1.setFirstName("Lucy");
        user1.setPassword("welcome123");
        
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
        user1 = userDAO.create(user1);
        
        assertTrue(user1.getId() > 0);
    }

}
```

User POJO

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private ObjectId id;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String fulleName;
    private String password;

// getter/setter below
}
```

Although getting good advice from prasad, I have difficulty to put the CodecRegistry to my database class, as follow...(I know it must be wrong)

```
    public static MongoDatabase getMongoDB() {

        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));

        try {
            ConnectionString connectiontring = new ConnectionString(
                    "mongodb_database");
            MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder().codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry).build()
                    .applyConnectionString(connectiontring)
                    .retryWrites(false).build();
            MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettings);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Update: I need to import below to make it works perhaps.

```
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders;
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries;
```

Comment: What is it you are assigning for the `User`'s `id` property? Is it the default [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/bson-types/#objectid) for a document's `_id`? In such a case, the system generates the value when a new document is inserted. Also note the `_id` value is unique.

Comment: @prasad_ yes, the default _id I wanna get because I know it is not recommended to create another uid (e.g. as userId in MongoDB). My aim is to get the _id instead of userId in the user entity.

Comment: So what is this:`user1.getId()`

Comment: @prasad_ the userId currently is null. I just declare it like working with MySQL to auto increment the I'd field. I wonder if I could set ObjectId to in user entity or even other entities as their PK field.

Comment: What is your `User` class? See how to use POJOs with you MongoDB Java at [Quick Start - POJOs Examples](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/).

Comment: Yes, you need to use the _codecs_ as you see in the examples to work with your POJO classes.

Comment: I think I need your help. I'm editing the question with my MongoDB connection

Comment: Also post the code for the User.java class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222509/discussion-between-stu-dent-and-prasad).